# Why is every element of this group upper triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, algebraic-groups

Let $V$ be an $n-$dimensional vector space and $G \le GL_n$.  If I have a complete flag of $G$-invariant subspaces $\langle v_1, \dots v_k \rangle$ $(1 \le k \le n)$, how does a base change to $\{v_1, \dots v_n\}$ make every matrix in $G$ upper triangular?

I don't have a proper understanding of how a base change works, and why it is equivalent to conjugation.

I know that if $T$ is a linear transformation, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then there exists a basis of $V$ such that the corresponding matrix of the transformation is of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} \begin{array}
\ \lambda & * & \dots &*\\ 
0 & * & \dots & * \\
\vdots & \vdots && \vdots\\
0 & * & \dots &*
\end{array} \end{pmatrix},$$

I'm not sure if this is relevant. It feels like there could be a problem as we don't have fixed basis in this way.

Refrence to where the claim is made: [A question concerning unipotent matrices and a basis choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261362/a-question-concerning-unipotent-matrices-and-a-basis-choice)

Comment: Do you know how to represent a operator as a matrix under given basis? The result is quite obvious since $Gv_k\in G\langle v_1,\ldots,v_k\rangle\subset\langle v_1,\ldots,v_k\rangle$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Honestly, I've forgotten most of linear algebra. I would appreciate it if you can maybe write a short answer explaining how this is all obvious, or provide a reference? I can see how the inclusion you wrote above is obvious, however, I'm not making a connection with the big picture here.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices), especially the reference 6 there.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Yes, that I understand. But then it is not obvious how elements of $G$ because upper triangular with the basis $\{v_1, \dots , v_n\}$.

Comment: $Gv_k\in\langle v_1,\ldots, v_k\rangle$ means $Gv_k = \sum_{j=1}^k c_{kj} v_j$, so what is the $k$-th column of the matrix representation of $G$, under basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$?

Comment: @CaveJohnson Humm. The $k$-th column would consist of the entries $c_{kj}$, with $c_{kk} = 1$? I think I can see what is happening now. Entries in the $k$-th column after $c_{kk}$ would have to be $0$, and so every matrix in $G$ becomes an upper triangular matrix with $1$'s in the diagonal.

Comment: $c_{kk} = 1$ because $Gv_k \in v_k + \langle v_1, \dots , v_{k-1} \rangle$?